# inneractive update GDR3 stretch banner

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've just installed a Windows Phone Update (GDR3) on my test device. I have a problem with an inner-active.com network.

After updating my banner it seems to be stretched.

If I open the app on a device that is not updated the advertising is seen clearly.

Has this happened to anyone?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My name is Noga and I'm the Community Manager @Inneractive.
Usually the banner appears correct, so I suggest you speak with our Support team.
Please go into your console and open a support ticket. I'm sure you'll get all the answers.

Let me know if there is anything else I can do to assist, my email is: 
noga at inner-active com.

Best,

Noga

Comment: I'm write to support two times but I had no response.. the problem exists. I did other tests and only on the device with gdr3 happen .. also with other apps